# PyCharm: Unresolved reference

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using pycharm and got the following red warnings in my `from ... import ...`. But it didn't ask me to install any requirement. Why is this happening and how do I get rid of the red thing. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does the code run? If not, you will want to install `pyspark` and add it to your python environment. Otherwise, if the code does run and you simply want to remove the red inspection warning, try adding `pyspark` to the list of `Unresolved references` you want it to ignore in File | Settings | Inspections - Python - Unresolved references. Taken from reference: [Pycharm - Resollving References](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/resolving-references.html)